# User is only able to like one post

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a Books class with the ApplicationUser as the author. In my ApplicationUser class, I have a list of Books which the user has authored (One-to-many).

The Books class also has a list of ApplicationUsers which is used to record to the amount of likes. However a single ApplicationUser can only like a single book. When the User likes another book, the like is removed from any previous books.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Likes { get; set; } //NEW
}

public class Book
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; } //Author

    .......

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Likes { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
                .HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(s => s.ApplicationUser) 
                .WithMany(s => s.Books)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); 

         modelBuilder.Entity<Book>() //NEW
                .HasMany<ApplicationUser>(s => s.Likes)
                .WithMany(s => s.Likes);
  }
```

It has to be a problem with the relationships. A single user can only like a single book. But a user should be able to like many books.
A like is added simply by `book.Likes.Add(user);` after checking whether user exists in Likes for that book.

But the one-to-many relationship between Book and the ApplicationUser who created the Book has to exist. But their is no requirement for a relationship between the ApplicationUser and the Likes.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult Like(string bookid, bool action)
    {
        Book book = db.Books.Find(bookid);
        var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (book == null || user == null)
            return BadRequest();
        if (action)
        {
            if (!book.Likes.Contains(user))
                book.Likes.Add(user);
        }
        else
        {
            if (book.Likes.Contains(user))
                book.Likes.Remove(user);
        }
        //db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw;
        }
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

UPDATE : So I added the Likes collection to the ApplicationUser class as suggested by @Alex Kudryashev. But im getting this error now when migrating and updating the database.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.BookApplicationUsers_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUser_Id' on table 'BookApplicationUsers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: What database technology are you using? Can you show the full code for adding a like?

Comment: Entity Framework, code first. Added the code for liking. Thanks @john

Comment: Why are the likes stored by the books and not by the users? Your current relationship is "book is liked by users" rather than "user likes books".

Comment: @RenanB because I want to get a count of the Likes when a user requests a book by calling book.Likes.Count.

Comment: `Likes` collection should belong to both classes to resolve `many-to-many` relationship.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I did that, getting an error thrown now as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your problem lies in the fact that you don't have a clear idea of the relations  between `ApplicationUsers` and `Books`.

Every `ApplicationUser` has Authored zero or more `Books`, every `Book` is liked by zero or more `ApplicationUsers`. Thus the relation between `ApplicationUsers` and `Books` is a many-to-many.

In EF code first this is written as follows:

```
class ApplicationUser
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every ApplicationUser has Authored zero or more books (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Book> AuthoredBooks {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}
class Book
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Book has been Liked by zero or more ApplicationUsers (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUsers> Likers {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers {get; set;}
     public DbSet<Book> Books {get; set;}
}
```

See [Configure many-to-many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

In `MyDbContext.OnModelCreating`:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
     // every applicationUser has zero or more AuthoredBooks
     .HasMany(applicationUser => applicationUser.AuthoredBooks)

     // where every Book has zero or more Likers:
     .WithMany(book => book.Likers)

     // we put the many-to-many in the following junction table:
     .Map(junctionTable=>
     {
         junctionTable.MapLeftKey("ApplicationUserId");
         junctionTable.MapRightKey("BookId");
         junctionTable.ToTable("ApplicationUsersBooks");
      });
```

As always with a many-to-many, although the junction table is created, you do not mention it in your `dbContext`. Whenever you use the ICollection, entity framework will know that the junction table is needed to GroupJoin.

Get all young ApplicationUsers that authored really old books:

```
var result = myDbContext.ApplicationUsers
    .Where(user => user.BirtDate > new DateTime(2010, 1, 1)
    .Select(user => new
    {
         Id = user.Id,
         Name = user.Name,
         AuthoredOldBooks = user.Books
             .Where(book => book.PublicationDate < new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)
             .ToList(),
    }
```

Or get all Software Books that were liked by one or morefemales:

```
var results = myDbContext.Books
    .Where(book => book.Genre ==  BookGenre.Software
       && book.Likers.Where(liker => liker.Gender == Gender.Female).Any());
```